# PHP can't setcookie()

Tags: php, setcookie

I'm having trouble expiring a cookie in php.  here's my code:

```
<?php
setcookie('reitinvestor_user', 'null', time()-3600,'',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie('reitinvestor_pass', 'null', time()-3600,'',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_COOKIE); echo '</pre>';
exit;
?>
```

Everytime i hit refresh, I get this result:

```
Array
(
    [_csuid] => 47dae7b6cd2d9e89
    [reitinvestor_user] => john
    [reitinvestor_pass] => 1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f
    [PHPSESSID] => 6027e370abad115e35b54b0be76befc8
)
```

I can do a setcookie with different key values and also expire them.  I just can't seem to do it for reitinvestor_user and reitinvestor_pass.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked whether you are in the same domain and path to change the cookies?

> […] a user agent
>     rejects a cookie (shall not store its information) if any of the
>     following is true:
>
> - The value for the Path attribute is not a prefix of the request-
>     URI.
> - The value for the Domain attribute contains no embedded dots or
>     does not start with a dot.
> - The value for the request-host does not domain-match the Domain
>     attribute.
> - The request-host is a FQDN (not IP address) and has the form HD,
>     where D is the value of the Domain attribute, and H is a string
>     that contains one or more dots.
>
> — [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt)